# how to wait for the URLSession to finish before returning the result from a function in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift3, urlsession

Hi i have a beginner question, where i cant find a good solution for in Swift 3. I hope someone is able to hlep.

i have the following code that will check a rest api if the user credentials are valid or not. I want it to wait for the resquest is finished and then return true or false.  now it is being send async.

Also any improvement in the way i check the JSON value's would be welcome too.

```
func CheckUsernamePassword(username :String ,code:String )-> bool {

    var validCredentials = false


    let urlString = "\(self.baseurl)/accounts/validateusernamepassword.json?username=\(username)&password=\(code)&api_key=\(self.api_key)"

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error URLSession : \(error!)")
            validCredentials = false
        } else {
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]

                if parsedData["validated"] != nil {
                    if "\(parsedData["validated"]!)" == "1" {
                        print("Login credentials are correct")
                        validCredentials = true             
                    }else {
                        print("Login credentials are not correct")
                        print("\(parsedData["validated"]!)")
                        print("\(parsedData["message"]!)")
                        validCredentials = false
                    }
                }else{
                    print("Json Parse error: \(parsedData)")
                    validCredentials = false
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error Parsing Json \(error)" )
                validCredentials = false
            }
        }

        }.resume()
    return validCredentials          
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot return something from an asynchronous task as a return value.

**Do not wait**, use a completion handler:

- Replace the signature of the method (the name is supposed to start with a lowercase letter) with

  ```
  func checkUsernamePassword(username: String, code: String, completion: @escaping (Bool)->() ) {
  ```
- Delete the lines `var validCredentials = false` and `return validCredentials`
- Replace all occurrences of `validCredentials = false` with  `completion(false)` and
  `validCredentials = true` with  `completion(true)`.
- Call the method

  ```
  checkUsernamePassword(username: "Foo", code: "Baz") { isValid in
      print(isValid)
      // do something with the returned Bool
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         // update UI
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: i tried the way vadian suggested,  the function does work, but there is a small problem , when i Call the methode i do a if statement to see if its true or false and change a text label on the screen. but it takes about 5 - 7 sec beofre the screen is updated.    How can i  change the performance

Comment: You have to update the UI on the main thread, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It helped me .. but how I can I pass back the result to the launcher view controller.The following code is having problems with some implicit declarations  `if let presenter = presenting as? ViewController {
                    if(self.correct)
                    {
                        presenter.bvalue=false
                    }
                }` 
Please advice.

Comment: macOS or iOS (seems to be macOS)? In macOS you have access to the `presenting` view controller so you can call a method directly.

Comment: @vadian Its macOS...I don't understand .. can you provide me an example,Please.

Comment: Assuming you have `launcherController` and `childController`. After segueing from launcher to child you get the reference to launcher with `let launcherController = presenting as! LauncherViewController` and run a method `launcherController.doSomething()`. You can put the code in the method where `dismiss` is called (Replace `LauncherViewController` with the actual name of the class)