# Avoid Swift Calling methods in viewDidLoad at the same time and getting "Index out of range"

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

could you give me a hand here? I would like to know how to call a swift function once another one is over, I think it is calling both functions at the same time. This is my viewDidLoad:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() { 
      super.viewDidLoad() 

        downloadJsonEscuelas(id_responsable: "5")
        downloadJsonAnuncios(id_escuela:("\arrayEscuelas[0].id_escuela!)"))    
}
```

The first function "downloadJsonEscuelas" fills the array "arrayEscuelas" with data, and the second function receives the data as a parameter:

downloadJsonEscuelas:

```
func downloadJsonEscuelas(id_responsable: String) {  

        guard let downloadURL = URL(string: Constantes.URLbase+"json/getescuelas.php?id="+id_responsable) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse,
            error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print("Something went wrong")
                return
            }
            print("Escuelas downloaded")

            do
            {

                let downloadedEscuelas = try JSONDecoder().decode([Escuelas].self, from: data)
                self.arrayEscuelas = downloadedEscuelas


                DispatchQueue.main.async {


                    print("id escuela actual:"+self.idEscuelaActual!+":)")
                    self.escuelaTextBox.text = self.arrayEscuelas[0].escuela!
                    self.idEscuelaActual = "\(self.arrayEscuelas[0].id_escuela!)" as String

                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error: ", jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume() 
    }
```

downloadJsonAnuncios:

```
func downloadJsonAnuncios(id_escuela: String) {

        guard let downloadURL = URL(string: Constantes.URLbase+"json/getanuncios.php?id="+id_escuela) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse,
            error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print("Something went wrong")
                return
            }
            print("downloaded")

            do
            {

                let downloadedAnuncios = try JSONDecoder().decode([Anuncios].self, from: data)
                self.arrayAnuncios = downloadedAnuncios

                print(self.arrayAnuncios[0].titulo!)   

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error: ", jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

I think it calls both functions at the same time, so it's not filling the array in the first function. When I pass the parameter as a plain number everything goes well, something like:

```
downloadJsonAnuncios(id_escuela: "2")
```

I hope you could help me here, thank you so much.

Comment: You could make `downloadJsonEscuelas`synchronous with `DispatchGroup` so the second function only gets executed once the first finishes.

Comment: I solved it by calling the second function into the first one's completion, thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert second call ( this `downloadJsonAnuncios(id_escuela:("\arrayEscuelas[0].id_escuela!)"))` ) inside the first call ( `downloadJsonEscuelas(id_responsable: "5")`) 's completion

```
func downloadJsonEscuelas(id_responsable: String) {  

        guard let downloadURL = URL(string: Constantes.URLbase+"json/getescuelas.php?id="+id_responsable) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse,
            error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print("Something went wrong")
                return
            }
            print("Escuelas downloaded")

            do
            {

                let downloadedEscuelas = try JSONDecoder().decode([Escuelas].self, from: data)
                self.arrayEscuelas = downloadedEscuelas


                DispatchQueue.main.async {


                    print("id escuela actual:"+self.idEscuelaActual!+":)")
                    self.escuelaTextBox.text = self.arrayEscuelas[0].escuela!
                    self.idEscuelaActual = "\(self.arrayEscuelas[0].id_escuela!)" as String 



                }

                 // here  
                 downloadJsonAnuncios(id_escuela:("\arrayEscuelas[0].id_escuela!)"))

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error: ", jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume() 
    }
```

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you so much. I don't get why I was getting that error though, is it that viewDidLoad really calls both methods at the same time?

Comment: yes both of them run at the same time , they are asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the second one in the closure of the first one

```
do {
    let downloadedEscuelas = try JSONDecoder().decode([Escuelas].self, from: data)
    self.arrayEscuelas = downloadedEscuelas

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("id escuela actual:"+self.idEscuelaActual!+":)")
        self.escuelaTextBox.text = self.arrayEscuelas[0].escuela!
        self.idEscuelaActual = "\(self.arrayEscuelas[0].id_escuela!)" as String
    }
    downloadJsonAnuncios(id_escuela:("\arrayEscuelas[0].id_escuela!)")) 
} catch let jsonErr {
     print("Error: ", jsonErr)
}
}.resume()
```

Comment: I solved it boing what you suggested, but Sh_Khan, it's just Sh_Khan said it first, but thank you so so much :)

Answer (score 0):

By default the code in viewDidLoad runs synchronously on the UIThread.
Your API call is running on a separate thread and is allowing your other method to be executed before it's completed.
You should probably be using a completion handler in your method so your second method only gets called after your api call completes.

See this answer for implementing [CompletionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804320/how-to-wait-for-the-urlsession-to-finish-before-returning-the-result-from-a-func)